# ICloud Password won't work on iPad but will on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, password

I guess the title spells it out. A bit of background into - I have an iCloud password associated with an old email. It also has a secondary email set up so I still get email when I reset the iCloud password etc. 
I had problems with my iPhone not backing up. I thought it strange as it shares the same iCloud account as my iPad. So I reset the password on my iPad but when I try to login I get told the password is incorrect. I've switched off the iPad and rebooted same things happens. I try my iPhone and I have no problems logging in. It's driving me made. Any suggestion, anyone?

Comment: Can you still access your account on https://appleid.apple.com/? If yes, try the password which works there on both the iPhone and the iPad.

Comment: Is Wifi turned on, and connected? That resolved it for me in a similar circumstance, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202586/icloud-password-broken-on-ipad-works-on-computer/